Drarry fanfic in which a spell makes Harry and Draco experience an imaginary life where they lived as friends and eventually got married and had kids
I don't remember the name, but I know it is on Archive of Our Own (AO3).
In the story, Harry and Draco are hit with a spell that makes them go into an imagination where they live their whole lives as friends and, years later, get married and have kids. However, when the spell is broken, they wake up in reality but can't avoid the feelings that they had during the imagination, so they are still attached to that fake life.
I remember a scene where they go to Malfoy Manor and it is very awkward, since, despite being there for the first time in real life, Harry remembers where everything is because he lived there with Draco in the alternate reality.
Please could you help me find it?

This is Dwelling by aideomai
From a review by HC:

Draco and Harry get cursed and end up growing up together and falling in love in this curse world where Harry's parents are alive and they essentially live a dream life then wake up with all these memories of them falling in love, and being so intensly together their whole lives just to realise none of it ever happened.


@Fligamon - Can you provide a plot summary for this fanfic or otherwise explain how it matches the one described by the OP? It would help other users decide how likely this is to be the correct answer.
